# Best practice for a 'provision' (also 're-deploy') git hook?

Tags: git, deployment

I want to be able call a git hook in exactly 2 ways inside my project folder:

1. update code to latest revision, which I will call *Soft Deploy*
2. provision empty dir (or to redeploy), which I will call *Hard Deploy*

A *Soft Deploy* is used most of the time.  It is simply updating code on, say, my Dev server with a `git pull`.  The git hook for this is plainly **post-merge**.

A *Hard Deploy* is where I am confused.  Sometimes I want to have the project redeployed.  Here is one example:  I want my Dev server to flush its database and reseed it with dummy data.  I don't want to do this flush on every git pull, only a *Hard Deploy*.  In git syntax, this might be a `reset` or `checkout`, or perhaps a `git pull -f`.   I would like if the git syntax was naturally equated in an average developer's mind with a *Hard Deploy*.  Perhaps a hard reset makes a person think a redeploy? Although something which occurs on the initial `git checkout` would be necessary, and a hard reset isn't something an average developer would run after a first checkout.

My thinking is **post-checkout** is probably the best hook to focus attention on for a *Hard Deploy*.  The main problem there is that when I bounce between branches on my local dev environment with `git checkout master` and `git checkout develop`, I don't want it to reseed & recache everything *each time*.  I would prefer to not have a 3-hook solution: 'deploy', 'update', 're-deploy'.  It would be nice to have the 'deploy' & 're-deploy' use the same hook for simplicity.

**So here is my exact question:  What git hook should I use when I want to *Hard Deploy* (as opposed to *Soft Deploy*) my project?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hook that allows you to easily distinguish your two use cases -- in hooks you don't get access to command line switches passed to git. The easiest way may be to simply put a tiny shell script inside or next to your repository and use that for hard deploying.

If you want to add some "syntactic sugar", you can define aliases in git. Here's an example for adding that alias locally inside your repository:

```
git config alias.harddeploy '!~/bin/myproject-harddeploy'
```

(The `!` tells git to run an external command rather than a git subcommand.)

Users can then just run `git harddeploy`.